# Python prints single quotes

Tags: python, list, printing, quotes, single-quotes

I have a Python project for uni which I've completed and works fine BUT it keeps printing single quotes like this:

```
('a', 'b') 0
('a', 'c') 1
('b', 'c') 2
('c', 'd') 0
('d', 'e') 1
('e', 'c') 3
```

How do I remove them?

Those letters are the names of teams from a file,the combinations are the matches that should be played, I put them into a graph and then I did the rest of the exercise. My only problem is the quotes thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the source?

Comment: @aks for m in matches:
    for day in days:
        if (m[0],m[1]) in day:
            print((m[0],m[1]), days.index(day)) I don't know if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have built a bunch of *tuples:*

```
team1 = 'a'
team2 = 'b'
tpl = (team1, team2)
```

And then printed them:

```
print(tpl)
```

The problem is that you're getting Python's default printout behavior for the tuples. There are a bunch of alternatives for you - defining a class, and then overriding the `__str__` method, for example - but what you probably want to do, in order to get things working, is just set up a more complex print command:

```
print("{} vs. {}".format(tpl[0], tpl[1]))
```

or:

```
print(tpl[0], "vs.", tpl[1])
```